# How to use file command with named pipe

Tags: bash

Original problem - I want to check a file format starting at every single offset of a given file.
To do that, the idea was to call the command `file` and find a way to call it starting at a chosen offset. But this command doesn't work:

```sh
file <(tail -c +10 nknukkodes.dat)
```

With this error message

```sh
/dev/fd/63: broken symbolic link to pipe:[26963]
```

I use WSL and I don't know if it's a WSL problem, I already did that but I don't remember if I use another way on Linux (with Ubuntu).

I could copy the file for each byte, but even the file are relatively small (200kb), copying at each offset is expensive in square of the file size: 40 GB of copy. How could I achieve this ? Either with calling `file` with a named pipe or with another approch ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest:

```
tail -c +10 nk_nuclear_codes.dat | file -
```